# Restricting access to nodes

Tags: nodes, hooks, users

I am new to Drupal and for some time now I am trying to figure out how to control access to nodes.
After figuring out that no module will give me what I want and deciding that I will have to get my hands dirty and write my own.

The problem is that nothing works and in no way I can restrict access to nodes.

To make things simple I tried blocking everything to anything in any way I found, but it makes absolutely no difference.

```
function mymodule_node_access_records_alter(&$grants, $node) {
  $grants=array();
}

function mymodule_node_access_records($node) {
  return array();
}

function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
}
```

The module is loaded by drupal, it is parsed (I get error messages when something is wrong), I tried clearing the cache, tried loading the module on and off, I disabled OG Access Control (I still have OG field access running).

The OG access modules are working more or less correctly (sometimes they block what you want them to block).

I am probably forgetting about something obvious but I feel like I tried everything.

Comment: Did you try logging out, and accessing the site as anonymous user, or with another account with just the _authenticate user_ role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for brief answers.

After a good night sleep I fixed the problem. The problem was with brackets (I had functions declared inside a function :/ ).
The strange part was that php server was only sometimes returning error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mymodule_......

As for the node access restriction.

```
function mymodule_node_access_records_alter(&$grants, $node) {
  $grants=array();
}
function mymodule_node_access_records($node) {
  return array();
}
```

Does not work. It is a pity because I would prefer to use the more powerful grants engine.

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
}
```

Works as expected.

A thing to mention is that I have to reinstall my module in Drupal for him to notice the new hook implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you are showing there are some mistakes.

- If you implement [`hook_node_access_records_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records_alter/7.x), you don't implement [`hook_node_access_records()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7.x) (and viceversa)
- If you implement `hook_access_records()`, then you don't implement [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x) (and vice versa).
- If you implement `hook_node_access_records()`, the other hook that need to implement is [`hook_node_grants()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7.x).
- Returning an empty array in `hook_node_access_records()` or setting `$grants` to an empty array in `hook_node_access_records_alter()` doesn't mean blocking every users from accessing any node. In fact, the function that invokes `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_access_records_alter()` ([`node_access_acquire_grants()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access_acquire_grants/7.x)) contains the following code.

  ```
  $grants = module_invoke_all('node_access_records', $node);

  // Let modules alter the grants.
  drupal_alter('node_access_records', $grants, $node);

  // If no grants are set and the node is published, then use the default grant.
  if (empty($grants) && !empty($node->status)) {
    $grants[] = array(
      'realm' => 'all',
      'gid' => 0,
      'grant_view' => 1,
      'grant_update' => 0,
      'grant_delete' => 0,
    );
  }
  ```

  When `$grants` is empty, it adds the default grant that allows users to see the nodes (if other conditions are met).

Even implementing the right hooks, a module is not able to stop every single user from accessing all the nodes, since:

- Users with the *bypass node access* permission can still access any node; this includes the first user created on a Drupal site
- When viewing a node that is unpublished, the user who created it can still see it, if that user has the *view own unpublished content* permission

See the code in [`node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7), in particular the following lines.

```
  if (user_access('bypass node access', $account)) {
    $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = TRUE;
    return TRUE;
  }
  if (!user_access('access content', $account)) {
    $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = FALSE;
    return FALSE;
  }

  // We grant access to the node if both of the following conditions are met:
  // - No modules say to deny access.
  // - At least one module says to grant access.
  // If no module specified either allow or deny, we fall back to the
  // node_access table.
  $access = module_invoke_all('node_access', $node, $op, $account);
  if (in_array(NODE_ACCESS_DENY, $access, TRUE)) {
    $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = FALSE;
    return FALSE;
  }
  elseif (in_array(NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW, $access, TRUE)) {
    $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = TRUE;
    return TRUE;
  }
```

Assuming you aren't interested in blocking the access to users with the *bypass node access* permission, or avoiding that users with the *view own unpublished content* permission can see their own unpublished nodes, then implementing `hook_node_access()` is the quicker way to avoid some users can see all the nodes, as long as the nodes aren't shown in a list of nodes, for example a view, or the front page, because in that case `hook_node_access()` is not even invoked.
Differently, the following code surely works and avoid some users can see every node.

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
}
```

If that code doesn't work, then there is an error in the code of the module your wrote, since:

- A single module returning `NODE_ACCESS_DENY` in `hook_node_access()` stops users from seeing a node (but remember the permissions part)
- Drupal core doesn't use `hook_node_access_alter()`, so a module cannot alter the value returned from your module, and change that value from `NODE_ACCESS_DENY` to `NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW` or `NODE_ACCESS_NEUTRAL`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the site as an anonymous/regular user - if you are logged in as a super admin (uid: 1) you will be able to access the nodes no matter the permissions.